# where does this.res come from when i read the npm package send

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs  and am learning how express work. I found a package call `send` on npm. So I read the code, but I have a question where does `this.res` come from.

```
SendStream.prototype.isCachable = function isCachable () {
    var statusCode = this.res.statusCode
    return (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) || statusCode === 304
}
```

I read the constructor of stream where the send module inherits. I do not find `this.res` in that constructor. If you can give a few idea to find. It will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `this.res` is only set when you call `.pipe()` [here in the code](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/master/index.js#L515):

```
SendStream.prototype.pipe = function pipe (res) {
  // root path
  var root = this._root

  // references
  this.res = res;                    // <=========== here's where it is set

  // decode the path
  var path = decode(this.path)
  if (path === -1) {
    this.error(400)
    return res
  }
  ....
}
```

And, since it appears that the purpose of this library is to stream data to an http response, it appears the way you use this library is always `send(...).pipe(res)`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i should learn again about the api of stream of node. and learn the basic use of the send package to understand the package. it really helps a lot. thanks